# Passing zsh function parameter to grep -E

Tags: bash, grep, zsh

### Background...

Trying to find which commit(s) last touched a specific file.

I can do this on the CLI piping from `git-log` to `grep` but I'm trying to wrap this in a zsh function, more for ease of memory.

Here's my function, and then here is the output I'd like to generate with it.

```
# match lines from git log that start with commit or include the
# filename I'm interested in and then pipe back through grep to color the output
glpg() {
  \git log --name-only | \grep -E ‘“$"|^commit\s\S' | \grep -B1 --color -E ‘$'
}
```

#### Desired usage and output

```
dwight:assets (add-analytics*) $ glpg clickouts
commit 6662418b8e68e478b95e7254faa6406abdada30f
web/assets/app/viewmodels/clickouts.js
web/assets/app/views/clickouts.html
web/client/app/viewmodels/clickouts.js
web/client/app/views/clickouts.html
--
commit cee37549f613985210c9caf90a48e2cca28d4412
web/client/app/viewmodels/clickouts.js
web/client/app/views/clickouts.html
--
commit df9ea8cd90ff80b89a0c7e2b0657141b105d5e7e
web/client/app/viewmodels/clickouts.js
web/client/app/views/clickouts.html
```

Comment: This is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).There is actually no need for `grep` at all: `git log FILENAME` will give you the log for commits pertaining to `FILENAME`. Use `git log --follow FILENAME` to follow the history beyond renames. You can also give multiple files (for example with globbing), although this cannot be combined with `--follow`.

Comment: `git log --name-only --pretty=oneline **/*clickouts*` should get you an output similar to your example. (With *bash* you need to set the `globstar` shell option for `**` to work: `shopt -s globstar`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems.

- You use Unicode apostrophes and quotes, ‘ and “. Replace them with ASCII quotes and doublequotes.
- You can't use \s and \S to mean space or non-space with a standard (POSIX) grep. Use `' '` and `[^ ]` instead to be portable.
- The list of all args is referenced with `"$@"` including the double quotes.

Comment: 1. Fixed.
2. My intention wasn't to mean 'space or non-space' it was to match a line that starts with `commit` followed by a space *and* a non space I'm guessing this would work ?`^commit [a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}`
3. Fixed.

Thank you.

Comment: @Luke Using character classes are a bit noisy but aid comprehension: `^commit[[:blank:]][[:alnum:]]` -- use [[:blank:]] if you're not sure if it's a tab or a space: if you know it's a space, by all means use a space.